# iOS standard elements language

Tags: ios, user-interface, localization

I have such a question: when we change device language, some elements in application change their language as well (For example delete accessory in cells or standard back button in navigation bar etc). Is there a way to change language for this elements manually globally for all application (write some code in one place), not with writing code for every element ?

Thank you for your attention.

---

I find solution for my question. If anybody interested in it look this link :

http://nicnocquee.com/blog/2014/03/13/run-ios-app-in-different-languages-quickly-in-ios-simulator/

Comment: Are you asking how to change the device's language settings from within your app?

Comment: @jrturton No. I don't won't to change device language. Only language for described elements. As example, device language - English. But I want standard elements such as standard navigation bar back button was in Deutch. The problem is I have a lot of standard elements in app, so is their a way to make such changes in one place globally ?

Answer (score 1):

Just localize the app by adding a `Localizable.string`. Then add the language and all of the UI element will be localized according with the language of the device.

Obviously you have to add the language of your device (if you have the device in Chinese and the `Localizable.string` are not localized in Chinese you continue to see the default language).

[image]

But if you are looking for a way to change only some element I think this isn't possible. All or nothing !

Comment: Automatically in according by the device language (if this language is added in the list of "Localizations"). In the screenshot, if you have the device in French, you will see the UI in english because French didn't added to the list.

Answer (score -1):

System elements, like the ones in your question, will display their text according to the device's language settings. I'm not aware of a way to force them to use a different display language (I can't imagine Apple being too keen on that).

You'll have to make your own versions of these standard elements if you want this behaviour.

Comment: Shouldn't this comment (and downvote) be on the other answer?

Comment: Sorry for wrong comment, already delete it. Downvote isn't mine. Please look at my edited answer, you'll see solution which I found.